# ogrListLayers cannot open data source

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, rgdal

I recently updated R and all of it's packages, and my code for reading in the layers of a geodatabase no longer works.

It works fine on my windows desktop, but doesn't work on my macbook (I change the filepath for the appropriate machine).

I get the same behaviour with any shapefile or geodatabase at any file path.

I'm essentially following the instructions listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340442/cannot-open-data-source-gdb-in-r

```
r1_gdb <-  "/Volumes/LaCie/2019 PRISM GIS clean/Region1_Cleaned.gdb"

subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("GDB", name)) 
          name    long_name write  copy isVector
50 OpenFileGDB ESRI FileGDB FALSE FALSE     TRUE

r1_lyrlist <- ogrListLayers(r1_gdb)

Error in ogrListLayers(r1_gdb) : Cannot open data source
```

What strikes me as weird is that the results of other functions leads me to believe this should be working fine.

```
file.exists(r1_gdb)
[1] TRUE

list.files(r1_gdb)
 [1] "a00000001.freelist"                         
 [2] "a00000001.gdbindexes"                       
 [3] "a00000001.gdbtable"                         
 [4] "a00000001.gdbtablx"    
.....
```

Here is info about my version of GDAL on my macbook.

```
> library(rgdal)
rgdal: version: 1.5-19, (SVN revision 1092)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20
Path to GDAL shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-4
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.
> getGDALVersionInfo()
[1] "GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20"
```

It works fine on my windows desktop. It seems I have a different version of GDAL on the two computers. But it's the windows computer with the older version of GDAL where the code doesn't work.

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.5-21, (SVN revision 1105)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/andersonch/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: C:/Users/andersonch/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-5
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.
```

Any suggestions as to what I should investigate?

Comment: Can you simplify this down to one `ogrListLayers` call on a single folder that is a GDB data source? The `lapply` over a list of them might be clouding the issue.

Comment: OK, sure. I've edited the question accordingly. The same behaviour happens.

Comment: Oh, does the `subset(ogrDrivers...` not return anything? This means your OGR/GDAL doesn't have GDB drivers. What operating system and version of everything are you on? What does `getGDALVersionInfo()` say? How did you install everything?

Comment: ya, I always thought it was weird that ```subset(ogrDrivers)``` didn't return any output. I included it because I was following the code from the linked answer above, but I never understood what it did because I never saw an output, even when this code used to work

Comment: Looks like you're on a Mac, which I don't really do, so I think I'll have to leave it for the Mac experts. You might want to list the full, unfiltered output of `ogrDrivers()` here too.

Comment: I made mistake actually, there is an output from ```subset(ogrDrivers...``` that I had missed. I've added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue but got a solution by using the file's absolute path. First, get the absolute path using the `tools` package.

```
library(tools)
r1_gdb <- file_path_as_absolute("/Volumes/LaCie/2019 PRISM GIS clean/Region1_Cleaned.gdb")
```

Then run the `ogrListLayers` function.

```
r1_lyrlist <- ogrListLayers(r1_gdb)
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Mac. For some reason I don't understand, ogrListLayers is incapable of reading the files if they are stored in my external hard drive. When I moved the folder to the internal memory of my Mac, it worked (also, only if the path is relatively short).

Comment: Sounds relevant, I do use an external hard drive too.